# Azure platform install

Tags: azure

Can we install a version of azure locally? In other words, can we manage an independent azure cloud? I am using the emulator. But I want a real azure system.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  At least partially.  See this link for more information about Windows Azure Pack.

http://www.microsoft.com/hosting/en/us/services.aspx

Features currently available include:

- Web Sites
- Virtual Machines
- SQL Databases
- mySQL Databases
- Service Bus
- Service Management Automation
- more features added all the time...

Comment: The new name for this is "Azure Pack", with details here:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-azure-pack/  In addition the features you mention, it adds Service Bus queues and topics.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we install a version of azure
>   locally?

No, Azure is Microsoft's proprietary cloud infrastructure, and as far as I know, it's not for sale.

Comment: I found this information: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appliance/

Comment: To me, if you wanted to get anywhere near that you would need to be a multi-billion dollar company who is a Microsoft partner. You may wish to look at OpenStack.org

Answer (score 2):

People who say it cannot be done are wrong!  Azure Pack has been available for a long time. For now, you can use AzurePack.  It is not an easy install but it is well documented https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469338.aspx

We have already announced the next version (called Azure Stack) which allows you to run the entire the Azure Stack in your datacenter.  You can learn about it directly from the product team on the team blog at http://blogs.technet.com/b/server-cloud/archive/tags/microsoft+azure+stack/default.aspx

It was announced that "Today (May 4, 2015) we are delighted to announce that as part of the 2016 wave of products we are bringing Azure to your Datacenter with the Microsoft Azure Stack, equipping you to transform your organization." The actual release date of the wave has not been released yet.  The assumption (by the name of the products) is that it will be sometime in 2016.

You can also learn more about it on Microsoft.com 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/azure-in-your-datacenter/ 
Once it is generally available either of these two links should give you the download link.

Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft and http://ITProGuru.com is my primary personal [and official] blog

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice video / presentation about Azure Stack that has been presented by Microsoft at Microsoft Ignite in may 2015 : https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3479

You can also look at Cloud Platform System that is a Private Cloud implementation of Microsoft Solution & Dell Hardware

Operating the Microsoft Cloud Platform System
https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Ignite/2015/BRK3460

Today CPS is running Windows Azure Pack. Next version of CPS will probably run Azure Pack

hth

Stanislas

Answer (score 1):

Azure Stack is not exactly the back-end software used by Azure in the datacenter, but is intended to be a consistent administrator, tenant, and developer experience to Azure. Workloads for tenants are meant to be shareable between on-premise and cloud.

Actual Azure software assumes scales of redundancy and management that aren't applicable at anything short of significant datacenter sizes.  Deployment, update, and management are handled significantly different between the scale of thousands of hosts vs. hundreds or even under 10.  See also: [Pets vs. Cattle](http://www.bing.com/search?q=pets%20vs.%20cattle%20datacenter)

Evaluation versions of Azure Stack (also known as Proof of Concept or POC) can be installed on hardware that meets minimum specified requirements for disks, memory, networking, CPUs, et cetera.  There are a number of online articles on this, including Microsoft MVPs who have built suitcase (and smaller) versions of this for under $5000 (US.)   These do not have the capabilities of the full product in terms of performance, fault tolerance... but they do allow evaluation of the user experience and programming surfaces using the actual products capabilities (i.e. it's the real thing, not a mock-up simulation.)

Full Azure Stack is currently partnering with OEMs for hardware + software solutions that are searchable on the web.

Comment: ObDisclosure: I work on this product, but this is intended to answer the meat of the question rather than shilling for the company.  This answer is on my own time, and doesn't represent an official statement from Microsoft.  I also realize it's necromancing an old thread, but it was one of the top topics for the product when I searched for current activity to be helpful on.

Answer (score -1):

You currently cannot install Azure locally. However Microsoft is working on an on-premises cloud offering, AKA - private cloud. I've no idea how much it will be, but if you want a local cloud you're looking at around $500k or more for a truly "cloud scale" and "cloud scaling" solution.

Currently Azure is multiple data centers, multiple regions, and hundreds of thousands of machines. This is something that one (even a very LARGE corporation) can't just purchase and emulate. Thus the reason it isn't offered as an on-premises or local installation.